# How can redefine attribute in abstract model?

Tags: django, django-models

Hello I have two models

```
class A(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

     class Meta:
        abstract = True


class B(A):
    slug = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

I get error `AttributeError: Manager isn't available; B is abstract`

How do can to redefine attribute in abstract class?
`class A` cannot be changedю

Comment: @heemayl sry. Updated.

Comment: When do you get the error exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract models don't have a manager on them because they don't map to a database table. They are used to define reusable mixins that you can compose into concrete models. To make `B` a concrete model remove the `abstract` flag and then it will have an `objects` attribute defined on its instances.

```
class A(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class B(A):
    slug = models.CharField()
```

As an aside, as things stand with your models this is a pointless hierarchy because the `slug` field on `B` overrides the `slug` field that is being inherited from `A` and therefore there is currently zero shared custom functionality between the two definitions. You may as well just have `B` inherit from `models.Model` directly.

Comment: `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
` I don't know... I added full code of my class on the gist with traceback. https://gist.github.com/m0nte-cr1st0/b65b98f28775cec92576307284c00abc

Comment: That is a separate issue altogether resulting from a misconfigured Django. You should google it further, it's a common problem. If you didn't use the Django tools for starting a project and/or an app you should circle back and do that. Or open another question. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project

Comment: Just have an external package. There, the slug field has the `unique_for_date` attribute. In my model, I need a `unique = True` field